# Not able to Open Website from Google Search

Tags: googlebot, robots.txt, google-index

My website `http://www.softnice.com` (WARNING: Possibly hacked site)

If I search in Google for "softnice" or "www.sofnice.com" I am not able to open my website. It shows:

> This www.softnice.com page can’t be found
>   No webpage was found for the web address: `http://www.softnice.com/`

I can open inner pages of my website from Google search, but the home page (including the cached page) does not work.

Please check the `robots.txt` file also.

Comment: Little more details would help understanding this better. From when this is happening? Have you changed anything recently?

Comment: Actually I come to know before a week ago, i had a word with my developer but he is saying that he hasn't done anything, also, i had a word with hosting company, they said, its an technical issue

Comment: also, please check the robots.txt file, if there is anything which is stopping for crawling and indexing

Comment: Robots is fine it seems. couldn't able to find anything that explains this. You can use  'Fetch' in Google webmaster tools and check once again. And there are two java scripts are there in home page just after char-declaration. what is it?

Comment: I dont have any idea about that java script, will have a word with developer regarding that, also if you find any thing , than please let me know, thanks

Comment: As @SuriBabu suggests, there are some unusual (cross-domain) JS files being requested - that looks malicious. One does not appear to return anything?! Also check your `.htaccess` file (if on Apache). If you see different/unexpected content coming from SERPs then it's a sign that malicious script might have been injected in `.htaccess`. Your standard 404 document is empty - you are relying on the browser default - is that intentional??

Comment: I need to have a word with my developer regarding this, thanks for the help